# How to have auto updated current time cell in GoogleDocs / Excel

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to create a spreadsheet that will allow me to track my clients' timezones.

I am using the useless `NOW()` function to calc current time, and then factor in the time zone value (+/- a #) as so:

`=NOW()+(E2)*TIME(1,0,0)`

But the cells dont update when I refresh. They just stay at whatever time was calculated or recalculated.

How can I get the current time to recalculate when I refresh the page so that all the times will be accurate?

Is there an HTML solution for this that I could use instead?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe try using this function instead of `NOW()`

`=GoogleClock()`

> **[GoogleClock()](https://support.google.com/docs/bin/static.py?hl=en&topic=25273&page=table.cs&ctx=tooltip)**
>
> Returns the current date and time according to your computer system.
>   Updates automatically each minute on the minute (unlike the NOW
>   function). No arguments are used in this function.

EDIT:

> [GOOGLECLOCK](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093329) is not available in the new Google Sheets. To get the same
>   results, use the NOW function and change your recalculation setting to
>   "On change and every minute" in your spreadsheet at File > Spreadsheet
>   settings.

Comment: that worked perfectly! thanks so much. i had no idea the solution was that simple!

Comment: The GoogleClock() function no longer works with the New Google Sheets... :-(

Answer (score 6):

Google official help file:

- The NOW function can be used to replace the GOOGLECLOCK function, which is not available in the new Google Sheets.
- Apply the NOW function and change your recalculation setting to "On change and every minute" in your spreadsheet at File > Spreadsheet settings.

Source:
https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3092981?hl=en

Answer (score -1):

Use `=NOW()`, then change the recalculating setting of the cell to every minute.

Comment: Could you add some detail on how to change the recalculating setting?

Answer (score -1):

=TIME(HOUR(NOW()),MINUTE(NOW()),SECOND(NOW()))

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. This answer was automatically marked as low quality. Please add a brief explanation of how this formula answers the question.